# Core Web API and website in single solution

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm working on an Asp.Net Core 2.2 website that will later on have mobile apps. My aim is to create a platform that does uses the same code as much as possible. Meaning, if I want to run a search or change user info, I want both the website and the API to go through the same code as much as possible.

Because I don't have any experience with the Web API, I was wondering, should I implement the whole thing in web API and consume it from the web interface or should I let my models ViewModels handle the logic and just call the this logic from Web API and MVC controllers? What's the common practice in these scenarios? I assume it's pretty common.

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than one device it is definetly better that you save your logic at Web API , server side. It should be basic Master - Slave (client-server) connection between your applications. Basically you should  get the data that you need from Ui and send to your API via json and transform your data, or do what you want, and than send the resultset back to Ui.

It is dangerous having logic at viewmodel, or controller of Ui. When you do this than when you change a basic logic than you have to change both sides. Beside this especially at mobile Ui you may not have enough sources to do some processes. It is better you use the Ui as dummy and just show what come from Server and send server the entered data.

Microsoft make a [sample project](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers) that may give you an idea. It is with microservices and dockers but still similiar with what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

you should use class library like DomainClass , ViewModel , DataLayer , Service
and Use Project.
Your layers are exactly the same.
You can write an Api controller in both the UI and the app, or you can write two different projects depending on you.
Since your database is shared then the data in the application and site are the same.